# Stop draggable element being removed when it is Droppend using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Im using JQuery Draggable and Droppable to drag an object from one div and drop it in another.

It drags and drops fine but when it does drop, it is then removed from the draggable list.

Is there a way to keep the object even after it has been dropped.

I have tried to append the clone back on to the draggable class but this didnt work.

Here is my code

```
       $(".draggableItems").draggable({
            scroll: false,
            helper: 'clone',    
        });

        $(".droppable-content").droppable({
            accept: ".draggableItems",
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(".droppable-content").append($(ui.draggable));
            }
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the `helper: "clone"` of the `draggable` and the use the [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function of jQuery to clone the element and add it to the `droppable` area:

```
$("#draggable li").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
    }
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/otauk4h7/1/)

Comment: $('.draggableItems').append(ui.helper.clone()); i tried adding this in to the drop function but it didnt work. Is this the sort of thing you meant?

Comment: Yes, but you may have to use the `ui.draggable` instead of the `helper`

Comment: I added an exemple if you wan to have a look at

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue. I found this post particularly useful.

[Constrain draggable element after it has been dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674299/constrain-draggable-element-after-it-has-been-dropped?rq=1)